# Creating an array of unique strings in a mongoose user Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, blockchain

I'm trying to create a user schema through mongoose that can have multiple wallet addresses.
I created the following schema:

[image: User Schema]

As well as the following function to update and existing user by adding a new wallet address.

[image: Adding a wallet address to an existing user]

Everything works fine when I tested it through Postman however I need to make it so that the array of strings in the user schema only contains unique values (without having to code it in the function but rather in the mongoose schema itself)

Thank you

Comment: Rather than `"$push"`, perhaps you want `"$addToSet"`?

Comment: Please don't share pictures. instead, add your code in a code format.

Comment: @nimrodserok will do from now on, thnx